# Listbox multiple selection Via code C# in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

This is a part of my program I have a string from sql and a Listbox, I want to select those Items in Listbox that exist in string.

**But the problem is this: just last item will be  selected by my code!**

In addition I use WPF .Net 4.5 and there aren't ListboxItem.selected property
and also  listBox1.GetItemText!

```
MYlistbox.SelectionMode=SelectionMode.Multiple;
foreach (var item in MYlistbox.items)
{
 If(Mystring.Contains(item.ToString()))
  {
   MYlistbox.SelectedValue=item.ToString(); 
  }
}
```

Comment: I read previous questions they couldn't help me!

Answer (score 1):

The item in `Items` collection is item data, not `ListBoxItem`, you should use `ItemContainerGenerator` to obtain the container which is ListBoxItem and use `IsSelected` property:

```
foreach (var item in MYlistbox.items){
   if(Mystring.Contains(item.ToString())) {
       var lbItem = MYlistbox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as ListBoxItem;
       if(lbItem != null){
           lbItem.IsSelected = true;
       }
   }
}
```

Also note that `ItemContainerGenerator` works only if the item is loaded and rendered. It's a pity that ListBox also uses a `VirtualizingStackPanel` by default. So the code snippet works only for visible items (hidden items won't have any container rendered). If your listbox does not contains a large collection, virtualizing may not be needed, you can then disable virtualizing like this:

```
VirtualizingStackPanel.SetIsVirtualizing(MYlistbox, false);
MYlistbox.UpdateLayout();//this is very important
```

If keeping using virtualizing, I think you have to somehow bind `IsSelected` to your viewModel using a binding with some converter. This approach is more complicated but more friendly with MVVM (and should be done if you're familiar with mvvm).

Comment: @user2576835 is your ListBox rendered? you can see it? This code should be executed when the listbox is already rendered.

Comment: Thanks God I fix it in another way!

Comment: Yes listbox is rendered before!

Comment: @user2576835 I remembered it wrong, the `ListBox` uses a VirtualizingStackPanel inside by default, you can disable virtualizing to make the code work, see my update at the end.

Comment: @user2576835 well if you set `IsVirtualizing` in XAML, everything is OK. However after setting it in code (as I wrote), we have to call `UpdateLayout` for the change to take effect. I know adding items to `SelectedItems` is a better choice but at least I would like to show you that the code I provided also works, in some case if you want to obtain the `ListBoxItem`, then that's the only solution.

Comment: @user2576835 also note that the 2 additional lines should be placed before the `foreach` loop. Otherwise it has no effect and may still throw exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i=0, i< MYlistbox.Items.Count;i++)
{
   if(Mystring.Contains(MYlistbox.Items[i].ToString()))
     {
       MYlistbox.SelectedItems.Add.(MYlistbox.Items[i]);
     }
 }
```

Comment: I think your code means `MYlistbox.SelectedItems.Add(...`?

Comment: Please provide an explanation of your answer so that the asker and readers can understand the solution.